# Hide class in HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've did my JavaScript assignment, where I had to do a Minesweeper game, it turned out better than expected, and it works fine! However it's easy to cheat in it, as I'm using classes, for the bombs, which show in the HTML file. Is there any way I can get around this? (The snippet below works, but the img files are missing)

```js
function $(szelektor) {
    return document.querySelector(szelektor);
}

function generateNew(){
    $(".matrix").innerHTML="";
    $("#eredmeny").innerHTML = "";
    game();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', game);

function game(){
    {
        const matrix = $(".matrix");
        const eredmeny = $("#eredmeny");
        let magassag = 16;
        let szelesseg = 30;
        let negyzetek = [];
        let zaszlokSzama = 99;
        let vegeVanE = false;
    
        function szamlalo() {
            var secs = 0;
            var id = setInterval(function(){ 
                secs+= 0.01;
                if(vegeVanE){
                    clearInterval(id);
                    eredmeny.innerHTML += (' <br>Idő: ' + (Math.round(secs*100)/100).toFixed(2) + ' másodperc');
                    }
                else $("#szamlalo").innerHTML = "Idő: " + (Math.round(secs*100)/100).toFixed(2);
            }, 10);
        };

        function matrixGeneral(){
            const bombakMatrix = Array(zaszlokSzama).fill('a​');
            const uresMatrix = Array(szelesseg*magassag-zaszlokSzama).fill('a');
            const jatekMatrix = uresMatrix.concat(bombakMatrix).sort(() => Math.random()- 0.5);
            console.log(jatekMatrix);
            console.log(szelesseg*magassag-zaszlokSzama);
            let idseged = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < magassag; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < szelesseg; j++) {
                    let negyzet = document.createElement('div');
                    negyzet.setAttribute('id', idseged);
                    negyzet.classList.add(jatekMatrix[idseged]);
                    matrix.appendChild(negyzet);
                    negyzetek.push(negyzet);                
                    $('#hatralevoZaszlok').innerHTML = zaszlokSzama;
                    
                    idseged++;
    
                    negyzet.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                        if (negyzet.classList == "a" || negyzet.classList == "a​") click(negyzet);
                    })
    
                    negyzet.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault()
                        flag(negyzet);
                      })
                }
            }      
        }
    
        function click(negyzet){
            let negyzetid = parseInt(negyzet.id);
            if (negyzetek[negyzetid].classList.contains('a​') && !vegeVanE){
                vesztett();
            }
            else{
                if (!negyzetek[negyzetid].classList.contains('clicked') && !vegeVanE){
                negyzet.classList.add('clicked');
                let aknaSzam = 0;
                let balSzelenVan = (negyzetid % szelesseg === 0);
                let jobbSzelenVan = (negyzetid % szelesseg === szelesseg -1);
                let tetejenVan = (negyzetid / 29 <= 1);
                let aljanVan = (negyzetid / 29 >= 15.5);
    
                if (balSzelenVan){
                    for (let i = -szelesseg; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                        for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                            if (i != j && negyzetid+i+j >= 0 && negyzetid+i+j <= 479 && negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) aknaSzam++;
                        }
                    }  
                }
                if (jobbSzelenVan){
                    for (let i = -szelesseg; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                        for (let j = -1; j < 1; j++){
                            if (i != j && negyzetid+i+j >= 0 && negyzetid+i+j <= 479 && negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) aknaSzam++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!jobbSzelenVan && !balSzelenVan){
                    for (let i = -szelesseg; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                        for (let j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                            if (i != j && negyzetid+i+j >= 0 && negyzetid+i+j <= 479 && negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) aknaSzam++;
                        }
                    }       
                }
                
                negyzetek[negyzetid].setAttribute('data', aknaSzam);
                negyzetek[negyzetid].classList.add('clicked');
    
                if (negyzetek[negyzetid].getAttribute('data') == 0) {
                    if (!balSzelenVan && !jobbSzelenVan && !tetejenVan && !aljanVan){
                        for (let i = -szelesseg; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​'))   click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (tetejenVan && balSzelenVan){
                        for (let i = 0; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                        tetejenVan = false;
                        balSzelenVan = false;
                    }
                    if (tetejenVan && jobbSzelenVan){
                        for (let i = 0; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = -1; j < 1; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                        tetejenVan = false;
                        jobbSzelenVan = false;
                    }
                    if (aljanVan && balSzelenVan){
                        for (let i = -szelesseg; i < 1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                        aljanVan = false;
                        balSzelenVan = false;
                    }
                    if (aljanVan && jobbSzelenVan){
                        for (let i = -szelesseg; i < 1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = -1; j < 1; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                        aljanVan = false;
                        jobbSzelenVan = false;
                    }
                    if (jobbSzelenVan){
                        for (let i = -szelesseg; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = -1; j < 1; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (balSzelenVan){
                        for (let i = -szelesseg; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​')) click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (tetejenVan){
                        for (let i = 0; i < szelesseg+1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​'))   click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (aljanVan){
                        for (let i = -szelesseg; i < 1; i+= szelesseg){
                            for (let j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                                if (i != j && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('clicked') && !negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j].classList.contains('a​'))   click(negyzetek[negyzetid+i+j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
                nyertE();
     
            }
        }
    
        function flag(negyzet){
            let negyzetid = parseInt(negyzet.id);
            if (negyzetek[negyzetid].getAttribute('data') != 'flagged' && !negyzetek[negyzetid].classList.contains('clicked')){
                if (zaszlokSzama > 0){
                    negyzetek[negyzetid].setAttribute('data', 'flagged');
                    negyzetek[negyzetid].classList.add('clicked');
                    zaszlokSzama--;
                    $('#hatralevoZaszlok').innerHTML = zaszlokSzama;
                    nyertE();
                }
            }
            else{
                if (!negyzetek[negyzetid].classList.contains('clicked') || negyzetek[negyzetid].getAttribute('data') == 'flagged'){
                    negyzetek[negyzetid].removeAttribute('data');
                    negyzetek[negyzetid].classList.remove('clicked');
                    zaszlokSzama++;
                    $('#hatralevoZaszlok').innerHTML = zaszlokSzama;
                }            
            }
        }
        
        function vesztett(negyzet){
            eredmeny.innerHTML = 'GAME OVER!';
            vegeVanE = true;
            negyzetek.forEach(negyzet =>{            
                if (negyzet.classList.contains('a​')){
                    negyzet.setAttribute('data', 'bomba');
                }
            })
        }
        
        function nyertE(){
            var jokSzama = 0;
            //(negyzetek[i].getAttribute('data', 'flagged') && negyzetek[i].classList.contains('a​')) || 
            for (let i = 0; i < magassag*szelesseg; i++) {
                if((negyzetek[i].getAttribute('data') == 'flagged' && negyzetek[i].classList.contains('a​')) || (negyzetek[i].getAttribute('data') != 'flagged' && negyzetek[i].classList.contains('a') && negyzetek[i].classList.contains('clicked'))){
                    jokSzama++;
                }          
            }
            console.log(jokSzama);
            if (jokSzama == magassag*szelesseg){
                eredmeny.innerHTML = "Gratulálok!!!!! Nyertél!!!!!";
                vegeVanE = true;
            }
        }
        matrixGeneral();
        szamlalo();
    }
}
```

```css
#eredmeny{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.matrix{
    height: 640px;
    width: 1200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

#jatekter{
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.matrix div{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

div {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  
  }

.a​ {
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/Tile.png);
}

.a {
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/Tile.png);
    background: grey;
}

[data="1"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/1.png);
}
[data="2"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/2.png);
}

[data="3"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/3.png);
}

[data="4"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/4.png);
}

[data="5"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/5.png);
}

[data="6"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/6.png);
}

[data="7"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/7.png);
}

[data="8"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/8.png);
}

[data="0"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/0.png);
}

[data ="flagged"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/Flag.png);
    background: blue;
}

[data ="bomba"]{
    background-image: url(../Aknakereso/Pics/Mine.png);
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js" charset = "UTF-8"></script>
    <title>Aknakereső</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ='jatekter'>
        <div>A játék lényege: minden négyzetbe vagy számnak (bal klikk), vagy zászlónak(jobb klikk) kell lennie, anélkül, hogy a bombára kattintanál! Sok sikert!</div>
        <div id="szamlalo">Idő: </div>
        <div class='matrix'></div>
        <div>Hátralévő zászlók:<br><span id ='hatralevoZaszlok'></span></div>
        <div id='eredmeny'></div>
        <button onclick="generateNew();">Újrakezdés</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Running that code does not produce anything usable. There is no resulting HTML, just a list of a elements

Comment: Because I'm using pictures for it, but the divs should be visible in the html viewer

Comment: Ah, I just looked at the embedded view. It was much easier to understand what you were talking about after opening the snippet in a separate window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that this is mostly unanswered a few minutes after creating this is the reason why you should try and code in English: it makes copy-pasting to StackOverflow so much more convenient when you do not need to translate your code for all the non-Hungarian speakers ;)

On a more serious note, the problem here is that you embed the state of the bombs in your HTML. You should not do that, as you get the *security* issues you saw yourself. The HTML should just show the *result* of your internal model, but you also use it as the *data store*. Split those in two! You should create a grid in javascript that you update on user results and then render that. That way the bombs are not user-accessible/viewable in the HTML.

Some pseudo-code to help you in the right direction

```
const GRAY_CELL = document.createElement('a');
// add some classes etc

class GridCell {
    constructor(x, y, hasBomb, grid){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.hasBomb = hasBomb;
        this.exposed = false;
        this.grid = grid; // required if it needs to calculate a number of how many bombs are in the vicinity
    }

    expose(){
        this.exposed = true;
    }

    // return the new state
    render(){
        if (!this.exposed) return GRAY_CELL.cloneNode();
        if (this.hasBomb) return BOMB_CELL.cloneNode();
        else {
            return NUMBER_CELL[this.calculateScore(this.grid)].cloneNode(); // return a cell containing a number
        }
    }
}

// assuming CSS Grid is used to control layout, not HTML
function renderGrid(grid){
    const elems = [];
    for(const x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        const rowLen = grid[x].length;
        for(const y = 0; y < rowLen; y++) {
            elems.push(grid[x][y].render());
        }
    }

    // update the DOM in some way
    replaceElemsInDom(elems)
}

// init the grid, doing stuff like grid[x][y] = new GridCell(x,y,true,grid)
const grid = initGrid(numberOfBombs, xDim, yDim);
```

Comment: Glad if it can help. I know it does not directly touch your own code, (as it was a bit hard to read Hungarian), but it should conceptually show you what you can do :)

Comment: Well, after posting some ideas came to my mind, and one of them actually worked really nicely!